# How to add individual timeout value per specific route using node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I need to set individual time to specific route using express from node.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
const express = require('express');
const timeout = require('connect-timeout');
app.use(timeout(30000)); //server timeout

app.use(haltOnTimedout);
function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next){
  if (!req.timedout) next()
}

// Test Router for GET request used for Health Check
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ msg: 'Hi There. GET request is working!' });
});

//Build jenkins pipeline

router.post('/buildPipeline', async(req,res) => {

  try{
    let usecaseResponse = await pipeCtrl.buildJenkinsPipeline(req, res);
  }catch(error) {
    responseObj = {
      status: 'error',
      msg: 'Error occurred while creating jenkins pipeline.',
      body: error
    }
    res.send(responseObj);
  }
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  const errRes = {
    status : 'error',
    msg : `Timeout error occured`,
    body : null
  };
  res.send(errRes);
})
```

Here I am using `connect-timeout` module to set timeout error and here I have set `30s` globally for each route. If the response did not come before `30s` then it will give timeout error and its also working fine. But here Now I have requirement to change or increase time for my 2nd route only `i.e-/buildPipeline` to 2min . so I need to add indivdual timeout value for some specific route using `node.js`. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a function which can check which router will be activated and based on the path you can pass the timeout value as it could be possible in future you might need different timeouts for other paths too. This is how you can achieve it:

```
app.use(setDynamicTimeOut(req, res, next)); // instead passing timeout here

function setDynamicTimeOut(req, res, next) {
 // if you need to apply more dynamic timeout on diff paths you can use switch case.
      if (req.path === '/buildPipeline') {
          app.use(timeout('2 minutes'));
      } else {
        app.use(timeout(30000));
      }
      
      next();
}

app.use(haltOnTimedout);
function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next){
  if (!req.timedout) next()
}
```

For more details on path, you can check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_request_object.htm).